# Running application in Intellij fails to compile domain - but bootRun works

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, grails-orm

I keep getting problems with Grails domain classes and using run action on Application

It appears as though the domain traits and transformations don't seem to pick up or process gorm traits correctly and compiler fails (had problems with columns without sufficient type data or bootstrap failing when I load a value into a property and it says the property doesn't exist etc.

Essentially I can't trust using the run on Application in the IDE and I don't know whether my domain classes are working or not.

However if I go to gradle view and 'bootRun' the same code it will compile and run successfully!

I've had this before and I don't know if its a grails failure or Intellij issue with Grails projects.

When I right click Application and run the command terminal shows it running like this

```
"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=7620:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\willw\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1951982944.jar lcm.network.app.Application
```

In my latest iteration this throws a compile error on the bootstrap (as opposed to an error on domain class) with this

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: maintainer for class: com.softwood.domain.MaintenanceAgreement
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:547)
    at lcm.network.app.BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1099)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:541)
    at g
```

However that domain class absolutely does have that property - see below

```
class MaintenanceAgreement extends Agreement {

    String level
    Map category = [:]  //p1 to p5 and sla details 

    //static belongsTo = [serviceProvider : OrgRoleInstance, maintainer: OrgRoleInstance]

    // implemented as unidirectional many to one !  mag point to org
    static belongsTo = [maintainer: OrgRoleInstance]

    static constraints = {
        level nullable:false
        //serviceProvider nullable:true
        maintainer nullable:false   //ref to maintainer party

        category nullable:false
    }
}
```

So you spend hours trying to sort spurious problems in your code using right click /run on Application.

I'm forced to have to use grails bootRun - which in this case runs the app just fine.

You lose some details when working this way as the stack trace for compile errors is not so clear.

Has anyone else had this problem with gorm traits processing domain objects in Intellij? Moreover how can I 'fix' the Application run action to fire all the right behaviours as bootRun seems to do?

Comment: Try right clicking on the package containing the domain classes and select rebuild...

Comment: Does Build | Rebuild Project action help? Does it help to enable Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | 'Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle' option? A sampe project would be helpful to check.

Comment: link to project is here - https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app.  However i did as suggested, right clicked domain folder and told it to rebuild <default> and i then right clicked and ran the Application.  And it worked this time!

Comment: i'll try some more tomorrow and see if it breaks again.  Query however if bootRun worked (i ended up using that all day) - what does the rebuild do and why does IDE seem to get out of kilter?  Seems a bit weird.  But thanks you for the tip in case it happens again

Comment: ps i just check my IDE and the delegate IDE build to gradle is not set in my present configuration.  I might try that as well and see what that does for editing /run cycle

Answer (score 0):

Mike W's answer seems to be the easiest fix. When you're in IntelliJ and edit your domain models it seems to get confused and app won't compile/run as expecting.

So if bootRun works, but running application from the IDE does not, then doing this tweak seems to get things back to steady state.

If you make edits to your domain models, right click on the domain folder.  Then click rebuild 'default' about half way down the menu.  Wait till complete, then run your Application instance again by right click `RunApplication <main>` in the menu and the app should start successfully (or with debug) from within IDE.

This is easiest answer and gives best feedback to the developer with minimal extra rebuild action to remember.